# Puppeeter - Catch no connection Error and do some action

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I would like to use a puppeeter to create a bot that will check if there is an active internet connection (sometimes it breaks it and I have to reset the router), so if the connection failed, the bot would automatically log into my router panel and reset it (this is not is a problem, but I do not know how to catch the lack of internet with a puppeter)

Thank you very much for any help and idea!

#update

guys, i know how to use puppetter, and implement this thing, BUT i dont know what should i put into condition, to check connection, for example i have

some loop lets say

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
if(NOCONNECTION){then do something}
 await delay(randomInteger(18000, 48000));
}
```

I just dont know, how to check if i have connection ;/ - so the problem is NOCONNECTION ;/

Comment: Have a go and try something, then come back if you run into any issues. Be sure to provide a [mcve]

Comment: That means you'd need to run the Puppeteer script in an endless loop so it can monitor whether you're online or offline. I'd rather use a different tool for that (plus cron or the like to run it every now and then) and if there's no internet connection, then I'd fire Puppeteer script to go reset the router settings.

Comment: updated in main post

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661420/handling-network-errors-with-puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can listen for [`'offline'` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/offline_event) or check [`navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) in an interval.